# Append custom field items to content from plugin

Tags: custom-field, metabox, page-template

I know you can use

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'modify_page_template' );

function modify_page_template($single_template) {
  global $post;

   if ($post->post_type == 'post' || $post->post_type == 'page') {
      $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-page-or-post.php';
   }
   return $single_template;
}
```

to replace the default theme and add your custom field items, but is there any way to do it without modifying the WHOLE THEME, instead just append the meta box data into the content?

Comment: `the_content` filter :-)

Comment: @totels Thanks! I didn't see that! The documentation can somethings be like a forest...

Comment: If totel's answer worked for you, the best thank you is to accept it. You can do that by clicking the check mark under the vote arrows to the left of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter to add code directly into the content.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_202010_modify_the_content' );

function wpse_202010_modify_the_content( $content ) {
  global $post;

  if ( in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {
    $content = '<p>New content here</p>' . $content;
  }

  return $content;
}
```